# How should you wish happy birthday to the (British) Queen?

Tags: register

(As it's the Queen's 90th Birthday today)

What is considered a polite way to wish the Queen a happy birthday? Is 'Happy birthday' too informal?

Comment: Dead Mouse, your question isn't really about the English language but about manners and customs. Unless you had an invitation to the Queen's private  dinner party (unlikely) you can just say  "Happy Birthday" or “[Many happy returns](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22Many+happy+returns%22)” on a card. I'm not sure if texts (sms) counts.

Comment: [Many happy returns Ma’am](http://www.arun.gov.uk/news-archive/many-happy-returns-maam-1266/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree it's not about the language itself, but I thought it would reasonably fall under 'usage' (I couldn't see any sign on http://english.stackexchange.com/tour that language-related questions on customs/etiquette were discouraged..?)

Comment: I just think it's too easy a question, but that's me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA arguably "Many happy returns Ma’am" isn't quite right from a formal point of view, as (as SGR says) "Ma’am" should only be used after 'Your Majesty'...

Comment: You should sing "God Save the Queen" for her.  Depending on your political leanings either this version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tN9EC3Gy6Nk or this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RvMxqcgBhWQ

Answer (score 3):

According to The Palace, there is no official way of communicating happy birthday with the Queen.

The only rule they have is that when first meeting the Queen, you say 'Your Majesty' or 'Your Royal Highness'. From then on, you refer to her as "Ma'am" as in Pam.

So, 'Happy Birthday your Majesty' or 'Happy Birthday, Ma'am' should be more than fine.

Comment: You forgot "Many happy returns"

Comment: Do you have a reference/link for that advice?